# How to add @ in mentionInput jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to customize Jquery mentionInput.
I have two function.
1) Button Click
2)Jquery Mention Input
I want to add @ when button click 
And then I want to put @ to trigerChar of MentionInput.

Is it possible to do?

```
function MentionUser() {
    $("#<%=textbox.ClientID %>").mentionsInput({

        onDataRequest: function (mode, query, callback) {
            var data;                
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/_vti_bin/Services/User.svc/UserList?username=" + query,
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                cache: false,
                processdata: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    data = result;
                },
                error: function (xhr) { }

            });
            // Finish Ajax Call
            data = _.filter(data, function (item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });
            callback.call(this, data);
        },
        triggerChar: '@',
        minChars: 1,
        showAvatars: false,
        elastic: false
    });
}


function SetMentionText() {
    $("#<%=textbox.ClientID %>").focus().append('@');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` to set the values to textbox:

```
$("#<%=textbox.ClientID %>").val('@'+$("#<%=textbox.ClientID %>").val()).focus();
```

Comment: I want to add @ when buttonClick and put the place : ** triggerChar: '@' **

Comment: replace the content with `@` in `val()` that i have used to set with content you want to append.

Comment: Requirement is a bit tricky. I want to change MentionInput value. The current mentionInput is allows you to "@mention" someone in a text message, just like you are used to on Facebook or Twitter. My requirement is when user click button, put @ to textbox. And then type character that a use want to find. Then show the user list as facebook.

Comment: How to replace it in triggerChar. I am very new in jquery.Can you explain more detail?

Comment: Currently I am also working on this. I successfully got the input and sent to my server. I need to parse the text in my java server and I dont know how to do it. For ex: my input is like "arun aa arun kumar". Value got is "@[arun](user:12) aa @[arun kumar](user:2)". How to parse this?

How to use getMentions(callback)?

Comment: @arunborn2win41: you should rather simplify the content on clientside when sending to server.

Comment: I dont see any general format to simplify. I cant split the input with " " or anything else.

Comment: @arun I did customized for it and I replaced @[arun kumar](user:2) when I found "arun kumar"  and handled by code behind(c#) for extracting name and links.

Comment: @arunborn2win41 if you use mentionInputjquery, it is processed by mentionInputJuquery and return @[arun kumar](user:2) when found "arun kumar".

Comment: @arunborn2win41 Did you customized mentionInput jquery file ? I did customized like the mentionInput logic.I did keyup event, up,down,enter,click,etc.. all are customized.

Comment: I customized the jquery file in such a way <contact>id:name</contact> such that I can parse the data easily.

Comment: How to parse '@' trigger character to mentionInput jquery when you click button.